# Solving three non-linear ODEs analytically in one variable

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

Any idea what is the best way to substitute to analytically solve these equations in y(x) ?

```
3 y'[x] /y[x] - m == g[x];

-2  y''[x]/y[x] - (y'[x]/y[x])^2 == g[x];

-3 ( y''[x]/y[x] + (y'[x]/y[x])^2) == g[x];
```

**My trail:**

Here is my idea, I think we can equal any two of them and eliminate g[t],

So for instance in case the first equals the second

```
DSolve[{-2 (y''[x]/y[x]) - (y'[x]/y[x])^2 == 3 (y'[x]/y[x])^2 - m}, y, x]
```

Which gives

```
{{y -> 
   Function[{x}, C[2] Cosh[Sqrt[3/2] Sqrt[m] (x + 2 C[1])]^(1/3)]}}
```

**BUT** this is not the same solution when the first equals the third or the second equals the third.

So how to solve the three equations together to give a single solution for y(x)?

Comment: 1. These three equations do not contain a(t). So, what is your question? 2. You have three equations for two variables y(t) and g(t), am I right? If yes, this system, generally, cannot have a solution. If I am not right, I assume m should be also treated as an unknown, is it? In this latter case, one deals with a nonlinear eigenvalue problem. Is it the case?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch. 1) Yes, I have two unknowns y(x) and g(x) -the question has been modified - 2) for the time being I take M as a constant, if you're saying when M is considered as a variable M(x), some solution will be available so let me know how

Answer (score 1):

The general solution of the first equation is

```
y =.
y = DSolveValue[3 y'[x]/y[x] - m == g[x], y, x]
(*E^ Integrate [(m + g[K[1]])/3,{K[1], 1, x}]*C[1]*)
```

substituted into the remaining equations gives

```
{-2 y''[x]/y[x] - (y'[x]/y[x])^2 == g[x],-3 (y''[x]/y[x] + (y'[x]/y[x])^2) == g[x] } // Simplify


(*{m^2 + (3 + 2 m) g[x] + g[x]^2 + 2 Derivative[1][g][x] == 0,2 m^2 + (3 + 4 m) g[x] + 2 g[x]^2 + 3 Derivative[1][g][x] == 0}*)
```

Only if these equations are true the solution `y[x]` holds for the three odes!

Comment: Thanks. I thought if there are unknowns less than the number of equations, then the system will be over determined or there will be infinite solutions

Comment: Knowing `y''[x]/y[x]==(y'[x]/y[x])' +(y'[x]/y[x])^2` the three equations can be transformed to `{ y'[x]/y[x]==(g[x]+m)/2, g[x]==-2 g'[x]/3+((g[x]+m)/3)^2 ,g[x]==-3 g'[x]/3+6((g[x]+m)/3)^2`